# GUI Calculator calculations

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I am currently having some problems with a GUI calculator that I am working on. The calculator compiles and does do calculations. To do a calculation you must first input a number, select a functions (+, -, *, or /), select another number, then press equals. After a equation has been performed the program must be cleared before continuing. I am having trouble figuring out how to make it so that the program does not need to press clear before continuing with the calculations. I want to be able to click a number, click +, click a number, click equals to get the answer then press + again to add another number to the equation. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class GUICalc extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JButton[] numberButtons;
    private JButton[] upButtons;

    private JTextField field;
    private double num2, ans; 
    private int op;

    // 0 = gridx 1 gridy 2 gridwidth 3 gridheight
    private int[][] numConstraints = new int[][] {
            {0, 4, 1, 1},
            {0, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1},
            {2, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 2, 1, 1},
            {1, 2, 1, 1},
            {2, 2, 1, 1},
            {0, 3, 1, 1},
            {1, 3, 1, 1},
            {2, 3, 1, 1},
    };

    private int[][] upConstraints = new int[][] {
            {1, 4, 1, 1},
            {3, 4, 1, 1},
            {3, 3, 1, 1},
            {3, 2, 1, 1},
            {3, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 5, 4, 1},
            {2, 4, 1, 1},
    };

    public GUICalc() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(666, 666)); //width & heigth

        GridBagLayout layout; // used to be private
        GridBagConstraints gbc; // used to be private

        layout = new GridBagLayout();
        layout.columnWidths = new int[] {60, 60, 60, 60};
        layout.rowHeights = new int[] {60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60};
        setLayout(layout);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            numberButtons = new JButton[10];

            numberButtons[0] = new JButton("0");
            numberButtons[1] = new JButton("1");
            numberButtons[2] = new JButton("2");
            numberButtons[3] = new JButton("3");
            numberButtons[4] = new JButton("4");
            numberButtons[5] = new JButton("5");
            numberButtons[6] = new JButton("6");
            numberButtons[7] = new JButton("7");
            numberButtons[8] = new JButton("8");
            numberButtons[9] = new JButton("9");

            for(int i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++){
            gbc.gridx = numConstraints[i][0];
            gbc.gridy = numConstraints[i][1];
            gbc.gridwidth = numConstraints[i][2];
            gbc.gridheight = numConstraints[1][3];
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2); 
            numberButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
            add(numberButtons[i], gbc);
            }

        upButtons = new JButton[7];

        upButtons[0] = new JButton(".");
        upButtons[1] = new JButton("/");
        upButtons[2] = new JButton("*");
        upButtons[3] = new JButton("-");
        upButtons[4] = new JButton("+");
        upButtons[5] = new JButton("=");
        upButtons[6] = new JButton("C");

        for(int i = 0; i < upButtons.length; i++){
            gbc.gridx = upConstraints[i][0];
            gbc.gridy = upConstraints[i][1];
            gbc.gridwidth = upConstraints[i][2];
            gbc.gridheight = upConstraints[1][3];
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            upButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
            add(upButtons[i], gbc); 


        }

        field = new JTextField();
        field.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        field.setEditable(false);
        field.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN, 24));
        field.setText(null);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        add(field, gbc);

    }


    public static void main(String [] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new GUICalc(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);     

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[0]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 0);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[1]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 1);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[2]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 2);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[3]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 3);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[4]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 4);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[5]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 5);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[6]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 6);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[7]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 7);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[8]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 8);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == numberButtons[9]){
            field.setText(field.getText() + 9);
            }

        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[0] && !field.getText().contains(".")) {
            field.setText(field.getText() + ".");
        }

        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[1]) {
            ans = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            op = 4;
            field.setText("");
        }

        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[2]) {
            ans = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            op = 3;
            field.setText("");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[3]) {
            ans = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            op = 2;
            field.setText("");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[4]) {
            ans = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            op = 1;
            field.setText("");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[5]) {
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());

            if(op == 1){
                ans = ans + num2;
            } else if(op == 2){
                ans = ans - num2;

            } else if(op == 3){
                ans = ans * num2;
            } else if(op == 4){
                ans = ans / num2;
            } 

            op = 0;
            field.setText("" + ans);
        }

        if(e.getSource() == upButtons[6]) {
            ans = 0.0;
            field.setText("");
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your program is that your doing your calculations on doubles, but your parsing the text as ints. Replace Integer.parseInt with Double.parseDouble, and it will do just as you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even notice I had used integer for that. All of the problems with the program have been solved. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

/* Simple Calculator full Worked*/

```
   import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    class Calculator implements ActionListener
    {
    JFrame f;
    JTextField tf;
    JButton num[];
    JButton btNum0;
    JButton btEqual;
    JButton btAdd;
    JButton btSubtract;
    JButton btMultiply;
    JButton btDivide;
    JButton btSolve;
    JButton btClear;
    JButton btDot;
    JButton btExponent;
    double TEMP;
    double SolveTEMP;
    String display="";
    Boolean addBool = false ;
    Boolean subBool = false ;
    Boolean divBool = false ;
    Boolean mulBool = false ;
    Boolean expBool = false ;     
    Calculator(String s)
    {
    String number[]={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
    int m=0;
    int x[]={30,80,130};
    int y[]={205,155,105};
    f=new JFrame(s);
       try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Error setting native LAF: " + e);
        }
    JLabel l=new JLabel("Welcome To ZeeCalc Calculator.. :)");
    l.setBounds(30,10,240,40);
    f.add(l);
    tf=new JTextField();
    num=new JButton[number.length];
    tf.setBounds(30,50,240,40);
    f.add(tf);
    tf.setEditable(false);
    for(int j=0;j<x.length;j++)
    {
    for(int i=0;i<y.length;i++)
    {
    if(m<num.length)
    {
    num[m]=new JButton(String.valueOf(m+1));
    num[m].setBounds(x[i],y[j],45,45);
    f.add(num[m]);
    }
    m++;
    }
    }

    btNum0=new JButton("0");
    btNum0.setBounds(30,255,95,45);
    f.add(btNum0);

    btAdd=new JButton("+");
    btAdd.setBounds(180,255,45,45);
    f.add(btAdd);

    btSubtract=new JButton("-");
    btSubtract.setBounds(180,205,45,45);
    f.add(btSubtract);

    btMultiply=new JButton("*");
    btMultiply.setBounds(180,155,45,45);
    f.add(btMultiply);

    btDot=new JButton(".");
    btDot.setBounds(230,155,45,45);
    f.add(btDot);

    btDivide=new JButton("/");
    btDivide.setBounds(180,105,45,45);
    f.add(btDivide);

    btExponent=new JButton("^");
    btExponent.setBounds(230,105,45,45);
    f.add(btExponent);


    btSolve=new JButton("=");
    btSolve.setBounds(230,205,45,95);
    f.add(btSolve);


    btClear=new JButton("C");
    btClear.setBounds(130,255,45,45);
    f.add(btClear);



    m=0;
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
    for(int j=0;j<y.length;j++)
    {
    if(m<num.length)
    {
    num[m].addActionListener(this);
    }
    m++;
    }
    }
    btNum0.addActionListener(this);
    btAdd.addActionListener(this);
    btSubtract.addActionListener(this);
    btMultiply.addActionListener(this);
    btDivide.addActionListener(this);
    btSolve.addActionListener(new Operations());
    btClear.addActionListener(this);
    btDot.addActionListener(this);
    btExponent.addActionListener(this);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setSize(310,360);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
                        {
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                        {
                        System.exit(0);
                        }
                        });
    }




    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    if(e.getSource()==num[0])
    {
      display = tf.getText();
      tf.setText(display + "1");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==num[1])
    {
    display = tf.getText();
      tf.setText(display + "2");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==num[2])
    {
    display = tf.getText();
      tf.setText(display + "3");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==num[3])
    {
    display = tf.getText();
      tf.setText(display + "4");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==num[4])
    {
    display = tf.getText();
      tf.setText(display + "5");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==num[5])
    {
    display = tf.getText();
      tf.setText(display + "6");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==num[6])
    {
    display = tf.getText();
      tf.setText(display + "7");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==num[7])
    {
    display = tf.getText();
      tf.setText(display + "8");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==num[8])
    {
    display = tf.getText();
      tf.setText(display + "9");
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==btNum0)
    {
    display = tf.getText();
      tf.setText(display + "0");
    }

    else if(e.getSource()==btDot)
    {
    String dot=".";
    display=tf.getText();
    tf.setText(display+ ".");
    }

    else if(e.getSource()==btAdd)
    {
    TEMP=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
    tf.setText("");
    addBool=true;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==btSubtract)
    {
    TEMP=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
    tf.setText("");
    subBool=true;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==btMultiply)
    {
    TEMP=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
    tf.setText("");
    mulBool=true;
    }

    else if(e.getSource()==btDivide)
    {
    TEMP=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
    tf.setText("");
    divBool=true;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==btExponent)
    {
    TEMP=Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
    tf.setText("");
    expBool=true;
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==btClear)
    {
    tf.setText(null);
    }

    }

    public static void main(String... r)
    {
    new Calculator("ZeeCalc Calculator");

    }


    class Operations implements ActionListener
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    //double c=1;
    SolveTEMP=Double.parseDouble( tf.getText() );

    if(addBool==true )
    {
    SolveTEMP=SolveTEMP+TEMP;
    }

    else if(subBool==true)
    {
    SolveTEMP=TEMP-SolveTEMP;
    }
    else if(mulBool==true)
    {
    SolveTEMP=SolveTEMP*TEMP;
    }
    else if(divBool==true)
    {
    SolveTEMP=TEMP/SolveTEMP;
    }
    else if(expBool==true)
    {
    double a=TEMP,b=SolveTEMP;
    SolveTEMP=1;
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
    SolveTEMP=SolveTEMP*TEMP;
    }
    }
    tf.setText(Double.toString(SolveTEMP));

    addBool = false ;
    subBool = false ;
    mulBool = false ;
    divBool = false ;
    expBool = false ;
    }

    }

    }
```